# biblatex footnote-dw use comma instead of colon for follow-up citations

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

How can I persuade biblatex (style `footnote-dw`) to use a comma instead of a colon in follow-up citations?

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  author = {User, Joe},
  title = {Foo},
}
@BOOK{bar,
  author = {User, Joe},
  title = {Bar},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}


\begin{document}
Test\cite[p.~1]{foo}
Test\cite[p.~2]{bar}
\newpage
Test\cite[p.~3]{foo}
Test\cite[p.~4]{bar}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The citation on page two should start with 'User, Foo and Bar...' instead of the current 'User: Foo and Bar...'.

Right now I use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\renewcommand\citenamepunct{\addcomma\space}}
    {}}
```

which works, but I'm quite sure that this is not the 'right' solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`footnote-dw` has a lot of customisation features, but that can make it a bit harder to modify certain things should you wish for something more complicated.

`\nametitledelim` defaults to `\citenamepunct`. `footnote-dw` defines `\labelnamepunct` to be `\nametitledelim` in citations. `\labelnamepunct` is used in full citations to separate the name and title. In short citations the separator is `\nametitledelim`. So if we change `\citenamepunct` we change things for first citations and for follow-ups as well.

We can set `\citenamepunct` to `\addcomma\spcae` and reset `\labelnamepunct` to be a colon in the fullcite macro.

To get idem citations right we need to explicitly modify the value in the punctuation buffer with `\ifbool{cbx:idemfull}{\setunit{\addcolon\space}}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  author = {User, Joe},
  title = {Foo},
  location = {BAZ},
}
@BOOK{bar,
  author = {User, Joe},
  title = {Bar},
  location = {BAZ},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand\citenamepunct{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \usebibmacro{footref}%
  \ifbool{cbx:idemfull}{\setunit{\addcolon\space}}{}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {}
      {\ifbool{cbx:citedas}
        {\addspace\usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
        {}}}}

\begin{document}
Test\cite[1]{foo}
Test\cite[2]{bar}
\newpage
Test\cite[3]{foo}
Test\cite[4]{bar}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This works – almost.  With this changed definition,  a first cite from another document with the same author uses a comma also instead of the expected colon.   I've updated the MWE to exhibit this issue.

Comment: @lemzwerg Ah yes, indeed. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: I've also  opened ticket
https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex-dw/tickets/29/ – maybe this gets eventually added to biblatex-dw :-)